# How do I run a multinomial logistic regression with mixed effects in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, multinomial

I'm trying to run a multinomial logistic regression with mixed effects. Let's say I have the following variables:

Participant (ten participants, each with 10 observations)
Word (ten different words, each participant sees each once)
IV (some two level grouping variable)
DV (can be 1, 2 or 3)

How would I run a multinomial logistic regression with ppt and word as random variables?

Here is some sample data:

```
ppt <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
word <- rep(1:10, times = 10)
IV <- rep(1:2, times = 50)
DV <- sample(x = c(1,2,3), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(ppt, word, IV, DV))
```

Comment: Search https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html for "multinomial" to find R packages that can do this ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best package for this type of model is `brms`, but this package fits Bayesian models so you'll have to specify priors. I've fit an example model without specifying them, so it goes with the defaults that you shouldn't use.

```
library(brms)

d$DV <- as.factor(d$DV)
d$IV <- as.factor(d$IV)

model_fit <- brm(DV ~ IV + (1|ppt) + (1|word),
                 data = d,
                 family = categorical())
```